# Alternate Access Mapping breaks web part

Tags: 2010, web-part, alternate-access-mapping

I have a web application with two access methods:

1. `http://server:22222/` (default zone)
2. `http://server.host.com/` (intranet zone)

This web application has a single SPSite with a single SPWeb.  Accessing the site with `http://server:22222/` works just fine.  However, most pages on the site (all web part pages with a single web part on each) return the usual "An unexpected error has occurred." with `http://server.host.com/`.

Please note that I can get to the homepage as well as one or two of the web part pages, but not all.  To me, this implies that there is some sort of coding error in the web part; however, the web parts work fine when accessed through the default zone.

What about these web parts would work through the default port but not the intranet AAM?

Comment: What web part is it? Is it custom? You don't specify.

Comment: Whenever an "unexpected error occurs," there is usually information in the ULS logs. Check there and post if you can't figure out the error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that someone had deleted the host header binding on the web application in IIS.  Still not sure why this had broken a few specific web parts, but everything seems to be working now.

Thanks for the input!